# Parallelization issue with Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a web service published through azure ML studio written in R.
I call this web service from a C# web api endpoint passing the content of a CosmosDb document.

When I call the Azure ML 100 times sequentially using the same document, I always got the same result (0.07152444869) which is the desired result. This is also the result I get when I import 100 documents from CosmosDb in Azure ML studio and run the code.

When I store 100 jobs in Hangfire, the calls are sent in parallel and the Azure ML webservice responds with two different results (0.04541421681 or 0.07152444869) randomly.

The Azure ML webservice is hosted in the West Europe region.
Since I cannot debug the azure ML webservice, I don't know how to fix this issue. Any tip ?

Comment: Are there any random shenanigans happening in your functions (e.g. `sample`, `runif`, `rnorm`...)? If yes, you might consider setting a seed.

Comment: We don't use any random function in the logic.